# jQuery .when() : Is there a callback function that fires when all requests finished regardless of their state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am using the `.when()` method of jQuery and passing multiple Ajax requests as arguments. For each ajax request, if it fails and enters the Ajax's error callback function, I am pushing the error message thrown by the server to a global array.

What I would like to have is a callback that will be fired when all requests are done, regardless of the success or failure of all the requests. In this callback in question, I will then print all the errors messages that have been pushed in my global array.

From my understanding and my testing, `.then()` callback is fired only when all the requests have been resolved, and `.fail()` callback is fired as soon as we have a reject, which does not allow me to get all the errors messages but only the first one.

```
sources = [ 'posts', 'comments', 'albums', 'photos' ];
requests = [];
ajaxErrors = [];
$.each(sources, function(idx, val) {
    requests.push(
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'GET',
            url     : 'https://myapi/' + val,
            success : function(data) {},
            error   : function(data) {
                ajaxErrors.push(data.message);
            }
        })
    );
});

$.when
    .apply($, requests)
    .then(function() {
        // Only fired when all requests are successful
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log(ajaxErrors);
        // If all request failed, ajaxErrors only has 1 element : ['Error retrieving posts, connexion timeout']
    });
```

Comment: You can use .catch to convert the rejected promise into a resolved one, thus allowing it to wait for them all to finish.

Comment: Take a look at [`.always()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/): **Description: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.**